# Erro Assertion failure: "(!"SetThreadContext failed")" in ..\win32src\thread32.cpp at line 434

Tags: c++

Estou compilando meu projeto C++ no CodeGear 2009 da Embarcadero, e quando começo a debugar meu programa esta mensagem aparece:

> bds.exe - bordbk120N.dll
>   Assertion failure: "(!"SetThreadContext failed")" in ..\win32src\thread32.cpp at line 434
>   Continue execution?

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender o porque deste erro e como solucionar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, pesquisando um pouco mais na internet descobri que a .dll ***bordbk120N.dll*** possui um bug quando a mesma é executada na plataforma Win7 x64 para esta versão 2009 e anteriores. Para correção deste problema, deve-se alterar um trecho do **bordbk120N.dll**. Segue abaixo os passos para correção deste bug:

**Tome cuidado! Não há garantias! Eu não sou responsável por arquivos perdidos, etc.! Faça cópia de backup antes de prosseguir!**

**Passos para resolução:**

1 - Feche o Delphi ou o C++ Builder

2 - Localize a biblioteca bordbk120N.dll (C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\bin)

3 - Faça uma cópia de backup

4 - Verifique que o passo 3 foi efetuado corretamente

5 - Abra o arquivo bordbk120N.dll em um editor Hexadecimal (o [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) funciona suficientemente bem)

6 - Procure pela sequência “01 00 48 74 47 80 3D”

7 - Garanta que essa sequência aparece no arquivo uma única vez

8 - Altere o valor “74” por “EB”

9 - Salve o arquivo

10 - Reinicie o Delphi ou o C++ Builder. O erro não deve mais ocorrer.

Estas informações foram extraídas (em tradução livre) do link abaixo:

http://www.monien.net/delphi-2009-windows-7-64-bit-debugger-crash-workaround/comment-page-3/#comment-7588

Comment: Eu tomei a liberdade de traduzir os passos para Português (pra facilitar a possíveis leitores futuros). :)